# call matlab function in C#

Tags: c#, matlab

I would like to call a matlab function in my C# project.
Here is my matlab function :

```
function [A,B] = estiamteBetaDistAlpha(mu,sigmasq)

syms x
a  = sprintf('x*((x/%f)-x) = %f *(x+1+((x/%f)-x))*((x+((x/%f)-x))^2)^2 ',mu,sigmasq,mu,mu);

aa = double(solve (a));
sel = find(aa>0);
pot= aa(sel);

B  = pot(1) * (1/mu - 1); 
A  = pot(1);
```

It solve an equation and give just the positive solutions.
I didn't find something like that for C# so I want to call it in my C# code to have the same result.

I find this way in internet but it do nothing :

```
 MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
            matlab.Execute(@"cd C:\Work\Predictor Material\PredictionAlgorithm\code\predictor\helper");
            object result = null;
            matlab.Feval("estiamteBetaDistAlpha", 2, out result,0.024, -0.002);
            List<double> sol = result as List<double>;
            Console.WriteLine(sol[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(sol[1]);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Any ideas to help me please?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What does "do nothing" mean? At least the two `Console.WriteLine` should print out anything or the code exits with an exception.

Comment: It print nothing there isn't exception..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not about the MLApp or any of its functions. The problem is your fifth line:

```
List<double> sol = result as List<double>;
```

With this code, sol would be a null object. Instead, use this code:

```
List<Double> sol = (result as Array).Cast<Double>().ToList();
```